# Jquery mobile 1.4 navigate to dynamically created page

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, navigation, markup

This is being bugging me for some time now so please help if you can.

So i'm starting with empty page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1.min.css'>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

Then injecting a jqm page into html :

```
$('body').append("<div id='index' data-role='page'><div data-role='header'><h1>Page Title</h1></div><!-- /header --><div data-role='content'><ul data-role='listview'><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li></ul><p>Page content goes here.</p></div><!-- /content --><div data-role='footer'><h4>Page Footer</h4></div><!-- /footer --></div><!-- /page -->")
```

Lastly i would regenerate/refresh markup of this page:

```
$("body").enhanceWithin()
```

Question is how do i transition to this page programaticaly as neither $.mobile.navigate('#index') nor $.mobile.changePage('#index') seem to be doing the job?

```
 $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("getActivePage")
```

returns

Object[div#index.ui-page]

```
 $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', '#index')
```

returns

Object[body.ui-mobile-viewport]

however the index page is still remains hidden from view .....

As you see im using jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1, Please help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

This is how you do it with jQuery Mobile: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/3eHGj/

#### Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $('body').append("<div id='index' data-role='page'><div data-role='header'><h1>Page Title</h1></div><!-- /header --><div data-role='content'><ul data-role='listview'><li>test</li><li>test</li><li>test</li></ul><br><p>Page content goes here.</p></div><!-- /content --><div data-role='footer'><h4>Page Footer</h4></div><!-- /footer --></div><!-- /page -->")
    window.location.hash = 'index';
    $.mobile.initializePage();
});
```

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on("mobileinit",function() {
                $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
            });        
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

## Explanation

Without initial page neither **`$.mobile.navigate('#index')`** nor **`$.mobile.changePage('#index')`** will work. Those methods require original page to exist before application can transit to another page.

Comment: Calling '$.mobile.initializePage()' will go through all current pages and do initialization on all of them. Is it possible to initialize only just added page?